# View mutual LinkedIn connections via API

Tags: linkedin-api, omniauth-linkedin

For the app I'm building, I'm hoping to fetch the LinkedIn connections of the user. I've applied to LinkedIn's [Connections API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/connections-api?context=linkedin%2Fcompliance%2Fcontext&view=li-lms-unversioned&preserve-view=true) though because I'm yet to hear back I've also been playing around with this great LinkedIn API on github: https://github.com/tomquirk/linkedin-api

That github API works great, as I'm able to fetch a LinkedIn profile's info, company info, etc. However, the connections endpoint doesn't return any results. This is the documentation example:

`get_profile_connections(urn_id)
Fetch first-degree connections for a given LinkedIn profile.

Parameters: urn_id (str) – LinkedIn URN ID for a profile
Returns:    List of search results
Return type:    list`

And this is my code:

`>>> connections = api.get_profile_connections('urn:li:fs_profile:ACoAAAylSRIBXNFRGjmGfTQsZZL04N8Sf_IyVao')

> > > print(connections)
> > > []
> > > `

When I run that, the returned list is [], so basically it's empty. Even when I try to return the connections of the account I'm logged in as, it doesn't work as well.

Would anybody have recommendations here?

Lastly, I'm very much a novice (have only been using low-code tools for a few months) so apologies if this question is super obvious!